# Akka 2.1.0 type checking of Tuple elements

Tags: scala, akka, type-safety

Using `Akka 2.1.0` I'm sending a message from one Actor (`ActorA`) to another (`ActorB`) and expecting the returned message to be an `Option[(String, String)]`. `ActorB` has a val defined as an `Enumeration` and this is being returned as the second element of the `Tuple` result.
`ActorA` uses the `Await.result().asInstanceOf[Option[(String, String)]` pattern (I know this is bad blocking behavior, but don't think this explains the behavior I'm seeing), and assigns the result to a val. Later when I try to pull out the second element of the `Tuple` result I get a `scala.Enumeration#Val cannot be cast to java.lang.String` cast exception. In previous versions of `Akka` this did not appear, and in `Akka 2.1.0` I would expect the `Await.result` operation to blow up. Can anyone explain what is going on here?

```
object MyEnumeration extends Enumeration {
  type Enum = Value
  val Foo = Value("foo")
  val Bar = Value("bar")
}

case class ActorA extends Actor {
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10000)
  val result = Await.result((ActorB ? MyMessage), timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[Option[(String, String)]]

  val validResult = result.get
  val validType = validResult._2 // this is of type Enumeration#Val not String

}

case class ActorB extends Actor {
  def myType = MyEnumeration.Foo
  def receive = {
  case MyMessage =>
      sender ! Option((validString, myType))
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind actually posting the code samples?

Comment: Added code example as requested.

Comment: `ClassCastException` in Akka 2.0.3, and that's exactly what should be if you cast `Enumeration#Value` to `String` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't actually work in Akka 2.0.3. As I understood, you parsed received message differently.

```
// enum
object E extends Enumeration { val a,b,c = Value }

// send 
case "Hello" => sender ! Some(("Hai", E.a))

// works
Await.result(rootActor ? "Hello", timeout.duration)
.asInstanceOf[Option[(String, String)]] match {
  case a: Option[Tuple2[_, _]] => // diff is here 
    println("" + a.get._2)
    a.get._2
}  


// does not work
Await.result(rootActor ? "Hello", timeout.duration)
.asInstanceOf[Option[(String, String)]] match {
  case a: Option[Tuple2[String, String]] => // diff is here
    println("" + a.get._2)
    a.get._2
}
```

Comment: Ok I need to re-examine what was happening before then - thanks for you explanation.